# Adding Bing Map into Blazor application

Tags: .net-core, bing-maps, blazor

I am working on a .Net Core Blazor project and I need to add Bing Map to my application. I have added the map and everything seems to work fine:
_Host:

```
<script async defer src="https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&&key=[key]"></script>
```

My javascript function:

```
function GetMap() {
    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
        credentials: "[key]"
    });

    var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(lan, lat);
    map.setView({ center: loc, zoom: 15 });
}
```

In my contact us page I have added the div:

```
<div id="myMap" style='position:relative;width:100%;height:400px;'></div>
```

The problem is that the map will not show up when I navigate to the contact page, it will appear only after clearing the cache (Crtl + F5)

I have also tried to call the function using the JSRunTime:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("GetMap");
    }
}
```

But I have received this failure:

> Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Cannot read property
>   'prototype' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of
>   null

Does anybody know the reason and how to fix it?

================

## Edit

I have also tried to remove the CallBack function from the javascript call and I get this failure:

> Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Microsoft is not defined
>       ReferenceError: Microsoft is not defined

Comment: I have solved the problem by adding a 1-second delay: await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));  // I still don't think this is the best solution but it has at least solved the problem

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have loaded the file on the contact page where I want to show the map. The delay was only to guarantee that the javascript files have been already loaded. I got the exceptions in the dev tool when I have tried without the delay.

Comment: GetMap is loaded either within the call back in the JS Url in _Host file or in the contact us page AfterRender